# I got this error ,can someone tell me how to fix this

Tags: angular

> core.js:4442 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

```
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.userDetails = this.cacheService.getUser();
            this.userName = this.userDetails.name;
          }, 1000);
```

Comment: Share your code as well, so the developer can understand.

Answer (score -1):

it means that the object "userDetails" is equal to null so you can't get the property "name" out of it, you must first make sure "userDetails" was assigned a value like:

this.userDetails.name= "Jhon Doe"

Answer (score -2):

Try to set your script at the bottom of your .HTML page

Comment: Please give some explanation on that.